# How to remove the comma using the replace in angular

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5ecbw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

***item.component.ts***

```
ngOnInit() {
    const data = ['.23.2 ms','.23.001 ms', '.23.81 ms', '192,101.02 ms', '1291,291.02 ms'];
    for (let x = 0; x <= data.length; x++) {
      console.log(this.formatData(data[x].replace(/ .+/, '')))
    }
  }
  formatData(num: any) {
    const [num1, num2] = String(num).split('.');
    if (!num2) {
      return num1;
    } else {
      return `${num1}.${num2}`;
    }
  }
```

expected output should be:

```
.23.2
.23.001
    .23.81
    192101.02
    1291291.02
```

What I want to do here is to remove the comma.

Comment: Nothing to do with Angular. this is basic javascript syntax knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const data = ['.23.2 ms','.23.001 ms', '.23.81 ms', '192,101.02 ms', '1291,291.02 ms'];

const result = data.map( item => item.replace(/,|[^0-9\.]|/g, ""));

console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Comment: I have a data which is ```.23.01, .22.001, .22.013``` how to display it?

Comment: what is your expected output for this ?

Comment: ```.23.2,
.23.001,
    .23.81,
    192101.02,
    1291291.02```

Comment: Can you check my answer? it producing same output

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove it like this:

```
string.replace(',', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

User `map`, `split`, `replace` and `join` methods.

```js
const data = [
  ".23.2 ms",
  ".23.001 ms",
  ".23.81 ms",
  "192,101.02 ms",
  "1291,291.02 ms"
];

updated = data.map(x => x.split(" ms")[0].replace(",", "")).join('');

console.log(updated);
```